# Christmas Hat Haiku

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2013, fun, haiku

In a discussion on travel, we were upset about the lack of possibility of getting some hats. Some certainly seem out of reach on the travel site. For example: The "Oh The Horror" hat. And so began a poem, a Christmas poem...

```
In a brief chat on Travel
Began a lament
"Cannot get a guru hat!"

Our highest meta
Is only twenty-five points
"That's not even close!"

So in a grand plan
In the full Christmas spirit
Came a post - right here!

Needing quality,
A laugh, a catch, cleverness..
We all love Haikus!

So five-seven-five,
Please lend me all of your ears,
Christmas hats for all!

A late edit in,
It came to my attention:
I suck at Haikus :/
```

---

```
This question's not mine
A gratuitous edit
Gets me Stallman's beard!
```

Comment: +1 for the idea. -1 for a bunch of horrible ugly non-haikus. +1 for the last one though, which is a real haiku and made me laugh (-:

Comment: When posting haikus, a new line you are after, end line with two spaces.

Comment: btw, i deleted a question last day (passed judgement, winter bash), then why did i not get any hat :( :(

Comment: I apologize / For barging in so rudely / Just for facial hair

Comment: I only write haikus for mugs these days.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because I hate hats.

Answer (score 19):

```
I just want a hat
I hope sense is not needed
Refrigerator

Another haiku
Just to get the Stallman hat
Photosynthesis
```

Comment: Possibly my favourite thus far!

Comment: All of us are cold. / Where would hats need to be chilled? / The antipodes?

Comment: #win :D love this one.

Answer (score 10):

I proudly present
The saga made of haikus
In hopes of a hat

I must get f1rst p0st
I will be the fastest gun
Need wonderful hats

Winter bash is here
Better than ever before
HATS will rule SE

Freehand red circles
Meme overloads will do good
Appeal to meta

I like unicorns
Unicorn unicorn yay
Cheap memes everywhere!

How to add numbers?
$(2) + $(2) ["dollar two plus dollar two"]
jQuery is best

Sekrit hats abound
Must figure out Chuck Yeager!
Pleading to the devs

Wait! Yes! I've got it!
**Eureka**! I've found out how!
Hint hint nudge nudge slap

Reanimated
I li-i-i-i-i-ive
Questions rise from dead

Peanut gallery
Comments comments everywhere
Yes! Got that upvote!

I see your point hat
Everyone wants unicorn horns
Hint: get it right here

I'm not listening
You must ignore somebody
For sekrit headphones

Wow, The Stallman beard
Suddenly random edits
Search for "wiki: yes"

Secret of the doge
Such hat very winter bash
Wow does it exist?

I'll keep expanding
In true fastest gun style
What's this "sleep" you say?

(Also, more hat-specific stanzas coming tomorrow)

Comment: I'm going to do that "sleep" thing. :-P this will constantly update

Comment: Keep it going, never know, there could be a haiku hat for 100 haikus ;)

Comment: -1 needs more jQuery.

Comment: So many stanzas! / More a saga than haiku / And more is to come!

Comment: @AmalMurali Fixed!

Comment: Now I *have* to upvote. :D

Comment: Can you be less cryptic about the Eureka hat? I can't figure it out :/

Comment: @Bohemian You can't **figure out**? (Hint hint...)

Answer (score 10):

Unicorns love hats
And my Christmas hat haiku
I has a bucket

---

Hypertext regex
TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ
A scary haiku

---

First day of Christmas
To me the Stack Exchange gave
Badass hat for free

Comment: Unicorns! Regex! / You've covered all the bases / Really know your memes.

Answer (score 9):

冬帽子
底冷え防止
被るべし

*Winter Hat,

Protects You from Piercing Cold Wind,

Better Wear One*

耳と角
一角獣の
帽子なる

*Ears and horn are,

a unicorn's

hat*

Comment: Charming, I like the wordplay in the Japanese, hehe.

Comment: Thanks @Darius, it's intentional, but doesn't translate so well.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if you care, but it's rare to end a poem with 連用形, usually it's the 連体形 (べき) or 終止形 (べし)

Comment: I originally had べし in my draft, but wasn't sure if it was right so I changed it to something I was more confident about. I switched it back. Thanks for the lesson @Darius!

Comment: Japanese, English / In parallel translation / You are an artist

Answer (score 8):

> 外人弁
>
> 多分十分な場合
>
> 旅行の帽子

Comment: I can't believe I just learned Japanese to post in this thread! d-:

Comment: Unfortunately it ain't 5/7/5 (6-12-7). What were you trying to say? "Foreign Dialect, At times perhaps enough, Traveling Hat"

Comment: @jmac: Yes something like "foreign dialect. might be sufficient. travel hat." (I didn't try to make it 5-7-5 in this English gloss.) I was counting syllables in the Japanese rather than morae, because I'm not really sure how to count them Japanese style )-:

Comment: 1 letter (one ひらがな) = 1 syllable in Japanese. So it's really just type 5 letters, 7 letters, 5 letters. The Japanese do cheat too sometimes though. Foreign dialect as 外人弁 made me chuckle though, thanks for that.

Comment: What about stuff like small kana? Are they also one letter?

Comment: It's easier to count in hiragana than kanji. Also, if you have a *properly* romanized version, you can count vowels, adding an extra for doubled consonants or finishing 'n'.

Comment: Anything that is one 'sound' is one letter, so はっぱ (leaf) would be 3 (since the っ is a whole-length pause), but しゃけ (salmon) would be 2 (since し and しゃ are both a single-length sound).

Comment: @GenericHolidayName: Yeah I was lazily counting in Romaji at the bottom of the Google Translate window (-;

Comment: Real Haiku are bloody tough, because they are so minimalist. I mean, the word for hat (ぼうし) is already taking up 3 syllables, while it's one in English. So you really have to be clever with your grammar choices and word choices. It's good mental exercise I'm sure, especially if you have good Japanese.

Comment: Lucky I chose gaijin-ben! (-:

Answer (score 6):

### HAT UNLOCKED!

[image]

Comment: When I next log in,
If that appears in my list,
My week will be made!

Comment: Embroidered digits! / But what if your wish came true... / Wear it to the pub?

Answer (score 6):

Submit your poems

Rhyming is not important

Count your syllables

Answer (score 5):

```
Who even needs hats?
Rep and badges are better
Ha ha, just kidding
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Japanese haiku --
They look very beautiful!
Wish I could write one.

"FUS DO RAH" mentioned...
"R-E-S-P-E-C-T"...
"Eureka" as well...

The syllables work.
The pattern, it is maintained.
The hat is pending.
```

Comment: +½ for the first one. -½ for the second one. +1 for the last one!

Answer (score 5):

> Keyboard not present
>   Press F1 to continue
>   Zen engineering?

Answer (score 4):

```
Seven-five-seven,
your first stanza may seem odd,
but not unheard of
```

Comment: It's Christmas, we're turning haikus on their heads!

Answer (score 4):

All sites are equal

But some more so than others?

Hatless in protest!

Answer (score 4):

> Winter is coming.
>   I was defending the realm
>   Before it was cool.

Answer (score 2):

> Winter bash is fun
>
> But StackOverflow centric
>
> No backpacker hat?!

Answer (score 2):

Hat equity now!

Emancipate sister sites!

Or we'll shave your heads.

Answer (score 2):

Mark what have you done?

I was happy with my hats.

Sorry for flooding.

Answer (score 2):

Hat fun. Haiku fun.

Then along comes "Tiny Tim".

And says "Bah Humbug"!

Answer (score 1):

Mark wants everyone

Equally able to win

All the hats they want

Answer (score 1):

One haiku per post?

Or entire anthology?

Are there any rules?

Answer (score 1):

Form an angry mob

Storm Stack Exchange headquarters

Box under Joel's desk

Answer (score 1):

Solidarity!

Came to fight for equal rights.

Boat fell on my head.

Answer (score 1):

Christmas Hat Haiku

Mark had inspiration, but

Is there a question?

Answer (score 1):

```
There's a hat for me   
I just have to understand    
How to do haiku.
```

Answer (score 0):

Q&A is hard

Let's go shopping for headgear

Gamification

Comment: fourteen haiku / in three hours is a lot / way too much free time?

Comment: In Ulan Bator / Hiding inside from the cold / All my time is free