# Will there be Winter Bash-related contests for Winter Bash 2014?

Tags: discussion, fun, winter-bash-2014

Last year, there were several [contests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212433/should-employees-with-head-injuries-be-allowed-to-post-on-meta) [related to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213769/work-is-hard-lets-color-the-walls) [Winterbash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212781/christmas-hat-haiku).

Will there be Stack Exchange-sponsored contests related to [winterbash-2014](/questions/tagged/winterbash-2014) this year?

Winter Bash Question
Will there be contests this year?
At least we have hats!

Comment: I hope that @balpha feels guilt for not having the hat I wanted and sends a Twilight Sparkle plush to the owners of the eureka hat as a sign of friendship

Comment: I think they have sent all their T-shirts already. But hope to be proven wrong! :)